# Intermittent "Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!" when loading AngularJS with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I load AngularJS through RequireJS. **Most of the time there is no problem** but once in a while I get the error:

> Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!

I know that everything is actually loading so the issue is not with RequireJS not finding the files.

Here is my RequireJS configuration:

```
require.config({
 baseUrl: 'lib/',
 paths: {
   jquery: 'external/jquery-2.1.1',
   angular: 'external/angular',
 },
 shim: {
   angular: {
       exports: "angular"
   },
 },
});
```

Here is how I load RequireJS and kickstart the load:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="requirejs-config.js"></script>
<script>
  require(["start"]);
</script>
```

I'm using AngularJS 1.3.0 and RequireJS 2.1.15.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Intermittent problems like this are usually due to a missing dependency somewhere.** Most of the time your modules load in the correct order but that's just due to chance. Once in a while, luck is not on your side and you get undesirable results.

The issue is that AngularJS uses jQuery only optionally. If it is present, then AngularJS uses it. If it is absent, then AngularJS will use a jqLite library, bundled with AngularJS, that supports a subset of what jQuery can do. One important difference is that a statement like:

```
angular.element('[ng-controller="something"]')
```

will work only if jQuery is available to AngularJS, and won't work if jqLite is used instead. If RequireJS loads AngularJS before jQuery, then AngularJS will be working without jQuery and the statement will fail.

**This can be fixed by changing your AngularJS shim to:**

```
 shim: {
   angular: {
       deps: ['jquery'],
       exports: "angular"
   },
 },
```

Comment: nicely put . good to know `AngularJS uses jQuery only optionally`.

Comment: Appreciate the answer! To accomplish this, I simply bumped JQuery.js to the top of the files [] in karma.conf.js.

Comment: @Brant That's a viable option if you are *not* using RequireJS. If you are, then the order in which jQuery shows up in the `files` array does not guarantee the order in which RequireJS will load jQuery. You have to set a dependency to guarantee the order.

Comment: @AlokMishra AngularJS does not use jQuery optionally. It uses jQuery lite by default so it will always have a form of jQuery, however if you load jQuery as a dependency before AngularJS then AngularJS will automatically use the version of jQuery injected.

Comment: @JasonRice jqLite is not "a form of jQuery". It is something particular to AngularJS, a completely separate code-base from jQuery, not produced by the the people who produce the jQuery (the jQuery Foundation).

Comment: I am not using Require js and already loading Jquery then angular js, but still getting same error in console.

Answer (score 34):

If you do not want to depend on jQuery then, ***provided that you can enforce the [browser version](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector)***, instead of

```js
angular.element('.mySelector');
```

use

```js
angular.element(document.querySelector('.mySelector'));
```

See [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) to find out which [browsers support document.querySelector](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).

Comment: The premise of the question is that indeed **I do want to depend on jQuery**.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity - this error can also be caused by attempting to compile an empty template string (e.g. one which was dynamically generated):

```
var someTemplate = "";
$compile(someTemplate); // throws (with jQuery lite at least)
```